# Last letter first letter

Tags: recursion, backtracking

I want to sort an array of strings.
A word must begin with the final letter of the previous word

```
example1 :
358 123 874 826 638 ===> ok
```

We have the possible solutions :12**3** **3**5**8 8**2**6 6**3**8 8**74

```
example2 :
521 894 189 577 400 ==> no solution
```

This is a backtracking problem.
I tried to solve this with java:

```
 package lastfirst;
 public class LastFirst {
 public static int sol[] = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};      
 public static int pos=0;
 public static boolean trouve(int sol[],int j){
for(int i=0;i<sol.length;i++)
    if(sol[i]==j) return true;
        return false;  
  }

 public static boolean ok(String t[],int sol[],int j){ 
     if(sol[sol.length-1]==-1)
         return true;
     else
     {
       String ch1=t[sol[sol.length-1]];
       String ch2=t[j];  
       return ch1.charAt(ch1.length()-1)==ch2.charAt(0); 
     }   
    }
  public static boolean solve(String[]t){
int i=0;
if(i==t.length)// Solution found, all words are used 
    return true;
   while(i<t.length)
   {
    if( !trouve(sol,i))// if the word is not used yet
        {
            if(ok(t,sol,i))// if the word is compatible with the solution
                {
                    sol[pos]=i;// Place word into solution table 
                    pos++;
                    solve(t);// Recursive call

                    pos--;  
                }
        }
    i++;
    }
return false;// if no solution is found
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String t[] = {"358", "123", "874" , "826","638"};
    //la solution existe :123 358 826 638 874
    System.out.print(solve(t));
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in Python. The first `search` function here have 2 parameters, `words`: subset of string array yet to be searched. `last` refers to the last string used in current possible solution we are examining, which defaults to `None`, or `null` in java.

In first `for` loop, every string in `words` tries to be the first string in solution. If rest of the string in `words` (i.e `words[:w]+words[w+1:]`) does return a solution (from our recursive call to `search`, checked in `if ans!=None`), we add that string to the front of returned solution and return the array. If it fails,`None` is returned, we try next string. If none of them finds a solution, we signal failure by returning `None` at last line.

```
def search(words,last=None):
    if not words: return []
    for w in range(len(words)):
        if not last or words[w][0]==last[-1]:
            ans = search(words[:w]+words[w+1:],words[w])
            if ans!=None: return [words[w]]+ans

    return None

words = "94 521 189 577 405".split()
print(search(words))
```

which outputs : `['521', '189', '94', '405', '577']`